# Google analytics: Returning Sessions after first acquired from specific referal

Tags: google-analytics

I like to know, how many returning sessions i got after first aquired from a specific refferal.

For example, I got 30 sessions from refferal A. 28 of them are new users.
How is it possible to check, how many of these 28 new Users returned to my website lateron (maybe trought direct?)

My goal is to know, how many returning visitors i got trought specific refferals.
Since i m not selling anything, i can t just set a specific HTML-Site as goal...my aim is to get returning visitors.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use segments!

Copy the 'New Users' segment, and then:

A) edit it so that it filters Users rather than Sessions.

This will show all the Sessions from these New Users. Then you can view the new vs returning report - all the returning visitors will have been new users within the reporting period. So if the report is for March then you the segment will show all new visits in May plus those same users' returning visits.

B) If you want to view from a specific referral source then edit the segment again and set the Traffic Sources field as well.

C) If you want to see all return visits in 2015 users who first visited in Jan, then set the 'date of first session' part of the segment to Jan, and set the report dates to all of 2015. This segment is actually the Jan 2015 cohort.

Instead of using a segment for (C), you can also use the Audience > Cohort Analysis tab to view cohorts, then simply create a segment for the traffic source you want.

Comment: Cool thanks, I used the cohorts view. I created a segment that filters on the traffic sources. I used this segment with the user retention metric and as a result i got day 0 = 100%, day 1 = 12,5%, the rest is 0%. That means from all users i got from this source, just 12,5% revisited my website after the first day of first aquisation...the rest didn t return. Is that right? (Just re asking if i understand it correctly, because many of my deccions will be based on these data :)

Comment: Yes, that's right - averaging across the relevant days in the table. Note that this is 12.5% of the *new* users during the last X days from that source who returned the next day. 12.5% is pretty high actually - I looked at a client ecom site with loyal customers and the return rate was 2.4% across all traffic. Though it's surprising you don't have any returning after day 1.